# Web2py getting label texts from SQLFORM properties or helper function

Tags: python, web2py

I have an SQLFORM and when that form is submitted, I am iterating through its fields to get corresponding values which are then used to generate pdf reports.

```
form = SQLFORM(db.sometable)

if form.process().accepted:
   //..... some code here.....
   for i in form.vars:
       // print value of the field name
       print i
       // print value of the field value
       print form.vars.get(i)
```

In above code, I simply want that instead of sending `i` to the pdf generation function, I would prefer the label being used in the actual form(Which follows the convention that underscores are replaced by spaces and all first letters capitalized. Like some_field will appear as Some Field in label).

So either I am looking for a variable in form that will give corresponding label or a helper/utility function that will generate the corresponding label from `i`

Comment: you can write  `db_field_label = db_field_name.replace('_', ' ').title()`

Comment: @GauravVichare that woks.